# How to check when a TextView's label is changed in android?

Tags: android, events, textview, listener

[DigitalClock](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/google/android/android/2.3.3/android-2.3.3-javadoc.jar!/android/widget/DigitalClock.html) is a subclass of [TextView](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/google/android/android/2.3.3/android-2.3.3-javadoc.jar!/android/widget/TextView.html). I want to update an interface based on when the time is changed on the DigitalClock. How can I create an event listener that checks when the text in the view has changed?

Answer (score 1):

Never used this on a DigitalCLock but i guess You could use a textchanged listener using addTextChangedListener. Check [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29).

Comment: Oh wow, i didnt see that buried in all the other methods. Thanks, I'll try it out!